# Conditionally call useForm once dynamically built schema is ready

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a particular use-case where I want to build my (Yup) schema dynamically (using data from the backend that defines the form).  Here's the main idea of it:

```
function myHook() {
  const [mySchema, setMySchema] = useState<AnyObjectSchema | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // setMySchema is called in here when backend responds
  });

  if (!mySchema) {
    return <SkeletonForm />;
  }

  // (bad)
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(mySchema)
  });


  return <TheFormGoesHere />;
}
```

but I can't conditionally call a hook ([ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation)).

But, if I move the hook above the conditional return, it's not happy about being passed `null` and I'm also not sure `useForm` would even update itself when the schema changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, you can use your own [custom resolver](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/#CustomHookwithResolver).

It looks like this:

```
function myHook() {
  const [mySchema, setMySchema] = useState<AnyObjectSchema | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // setMySchema is called in here when backend responds
  });

  const resolver = useYupValidationResolver(mySchema);

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
  } = useForm({
    resolver
  });

  if (!mySchema) {
    return <SkeletonForm />;
  }

  return <TheFormGoesHere />;
}


function useYupValidationResolver(
  validationSchema: AnyObjectSchema | null
): any {
  // This hook is taken from here: 
  // https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/#CustomHookwithResolver
  // just updated to handle a null validationSchema.
  return useCallback(
    async (data: any) => {
      if (validationSchema === null) {
        return {
          values: {},
          errors: {},
        };
      }
      try {
        const values = await validationSchema.validate(data, {
          abortEarly: false,
        });

        return {
          values,
          errors: {},
        };
      } catch (errors: any) {
        return {
          values: {},
          errors: errors.inner.reduce(
            (allErrors: any, currentError: any) => ({
              ...allErrors,
              [currentError.path]: {
                type: currentError.type ?? "validation",
                message: currentError.message,
              },
            }),
            {}
          ),
        };
      }
    },
    [validationSchema]
  );
}
```